# How to safely remove an SDHC card without disabling the SDHC USB adapter? (Windows)

Tags: windows, sd-card, usb-storage

I have a USB card adapter I want to leave attached to my PC forever. When I insert a card, write things to it, and then I want to remove it, I don't have an option to just commit to that card -- just to remove the entire USB device, as you can see. (This is Windows Server 2008.)

[image: My System Tray]

If I select that and then remove and reinsert the card, Windows no longer recognizes it. I have to pull the reader and plug it into the USB again.

What is the proper practice here? Should I just wait a bit for data to commit and then pull the card? How can I tell it isn't still writing cached data?

Comment: Most newer card readers have an indicator light to let you know when it's done. If yours lacks this feature, I'd give it a sec and then pull it. I've known people who went years without even knowing about the "safely remove" option, never lost data... just waiting did the job for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of times you can just right click on the drive and pick Eject.

Comment: That's what I do.  Right click on the drive / Eject, then Windows will tell you when it's safe to remove the card (usually immediately).

Answer (score 0):

If, when you double click on the icon (instead of right-clicking), you are given a similar screen to below, then you should be able to remove just one device from the hub.

Note: I have not tested this!

[image]